# Networking with people who are not from the HR

Tags: hiring-process, job-search, networking

If you're networking with people who are not from the HR, how can you benefit from knowing them? For example, as a college student, if you reach out to those who are not from the HR but employees in the companies that you like, how can you use that to improve your odds of getting in? Would it be inappropriate to ask them to write you a referral or an email to the HR?

Comment: If you get to know potential co-workers, they can introduce you to the hiring manager. If you already know the hiring manager at the point when you apply for the job, he or she will instruct HR to send you through unless they can find a more qualified candidate.  In short, HR is no longer acting as a filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If you're networking with people who are not from the HR, how can you
>   benefit from knowing them?

In many small companies, there isn't an HR department you do realize, yes? In this case, everyone from the CEO and founders to the minions on the front line are all going to be outside of HR and knowing any of them may help get you in the door if the company is thinking of expanding but doesn't want to go through the chore of posting job ads to get a flood of applicants.

> For example, as a college student, if you reach out to those who are
>   not from the HR but employees in the companies that you like, how can
>   you use that to improve your odds of getting in?

You can use it by finding out more about a possible opening that you could use to tailor your resume and cover letter to fit that niche. There could even be possibly being connected to a hiring manager which would be way better than HR as this is who makes the decision about who to hire. This is how I would use such a connection unless you are looking at huge companies that are likely to be quite bureaucratic.

> Would it be
>   inappropriate to ask them to write you a referral or an email to the
>   HR?

Unless your desired job is in HR, I question the useful of this approach. If you want to work in the IT department for example, the chances of an HR recommendation being useful could well be quite low as a development manager may think, "What the heck does HR know about what we really do here?" Consider what would be the point of that referral or e-mail going to HR. Is it to get the meeting you could get otherwise? Is it to find out if the company is hiring? The reason I have the qualifier there is that if you do work in HR then it may well be worthwhile to have connections in the desired department you want to work.

Answer (score 1):

These days most of the job opportunities are not advertised I think around 60-70%. So if you are only looking for new roles on job and another sites I am sure about that you chose the harder way. At the moment I am working as a tech talent scout and recognizing the same situation as I am mentioned that earlier.

The bottom line is that if you have some desired companies and roles feel free to get in touch with the non HR related guys at offline events or on-line forums\blogs and so on. These steps might useful for you because several times not the HR decides for the hiring but the project manager\senior developer....and so on.. has the last veto regarding the process. Respectively if you get on well with the "would be" co-workers they could promote and introduce you as well if they know any empty position.

In a nutshell you will gain a lot of inside information\new acquaintances\undercover opportunities if you come into contact with the employees....let's do it:)

Answer (score 0):

Many times, people begin a task without considering the purpose or desired outcome. And when it comes out to be positive, we take that in our stride. Likewise, you don't know the employee of a company may indirectly help you apart from HR.